# How to translate or change the title off a bundle item

Tags: multistore, bundle, bundle-product, transaction

I am setting up a new store view and i would like to share the products between both store views. The products i am using are for 95% the same for both store views. One of the things i need to change is the title off  the bundle item. Is this possible? I can not fiend any function that does this.

Switching between store views does not work because it translates the title for every store view.

**edit answer: Wow, how did i miss that, 1cm below is the store view title.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *default title* is the admin value, the *store view title* is shown in the frontend.

Switch in the upperleft corner to the correct storeview to change the title for specific websites.